# Rails 3 output flushing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I "flush" output in Ruby on Rails 3?

In PHP  I would do something like the following:

```
$i = 0;
$total = count($result);
foreach ( $result as $item ) {
    $i++;
    time_consuming_action($item);
    echo "Finished $i of $total<br>";
    flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do believe there is a plugin for that.

https://github.com/oggy/template_streaming

Answer (score 2):

```
STDOUT.flush
```

works for regular Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

template_streaming does not support Rails 3, yet...

https://github.com/oggy/template_streaming/issues/closed#issue/4